# Unable to use composer on windows 10

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I've installed composer via the exe available on the composer website but when I run «composer install» on my freshly cloned repo, I got this error:

> composer install
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>
> Package operations: 84 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>
> - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.2.0): Downloading (100%)
>
> Downloading (100%)
>
> Downloading (100%)    Failed to download ocramius/package-versions from dist: The "https://codeload.github.com/Ocramius/PackageVersions/legacy.zip/ad8a245decad4897cc6b432743913dad0d69753c" file could not be written to C:\Users\littl\Documents\PhpStorm\interrogator\vendor/ocramius/package-versions/033201643b71b6e284b58c9a7b0d8905: failed to open stream: Permission denied
>
> Now trying to download from source
>
> - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.2.0): Cloning ad8a245dec from cache
>
>   [RuntimeException]
>     Failed to clone https://github.com/Ocramius/PackageVersions.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.
> - https://github.com/Ocramius/PackageVersions.git
>     fatal: destination path 'C:\Users\littl\Documents\PhpStorm\interrogator\vendor\ocramius\package-versions' already
>     exists and is not an empty directory.
> - git@github.com:Ocramius/PackageVersions.git
>     fatal: destination path 'C:\Users\littl\Documents\PhpStorm\interrogator\vendor\ocramius\package-versions' already
>     exists and is not an empty directory.

I've tried to use `composer.phar` instead but same issue.

Of course, I've totally removed the `vendor` directory and started again, same issue.

I've also noticed the «file could not be written» error, but I'm running composer with an Admin account on Win 10 and composer is able to create `vendor` directory by itself, so it should be good.

What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

> destination path 'C:\Users\littl\Documents\PhpStorm\interrogator\vendor\ocramius\package-versions' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Fix this manually.